# Guidance on adding filter expression to query

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, predicatebuilder, linqkit

The application I am working on produces reports. I am tryingto implement some of the filtering which can involve up to several dozen fields in various combinations. I had previously used Dapper with string concatenation to build out the SQL but am trying to move to EF 7. It was not to difficult to implement some of the simpler filters using LinqKit with the PredicateBuilder. However, I am a little stuck with this one. The concept is to filter by a field in a child table while having the children tables linked
by a non-key field pulling the related information. The below code is a rough representation.

```cs
public partial class Person
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string AltId {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
public partial class Employee
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int PersonId {get; set;}
}
public partial class Student
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int PersonId {get; set;}                 // FK to Person
    public virtual ICollection<StudentTestAvailability> StudentTestAvailability { get; } = new List<StudentTestAvailability>();
    public virtual ICollection<StudentTestHistory> StudentTestHistory { get; } = new List<StudentTestHistory>();
}
public partial class StudentTestAvailability
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int StudentId {get; set;}                // FK to Student
    public DateTime DateAvailable {get; set;}
    public int LocationId {get; set;}               // FK to Locations
    public int TestNameId {get; set;}               // FK to Test names
    public virtual TestNames TestNames { get; set; }
    public virtual TestLocations TestLocations { get; set; }
}
public partial class StudentTestHistory
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int StudentId {get; set;}                // FK to Student
    public DateTime DateTaken {get; set;}
    public int LocationId {get; set;}               // FK to Locations
    public int TestNameId {get; set;}               // FK to Test names
    public virtual TestNames TestNames { get; set; }
    public virtual TestLocations TestLocations { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class ReportRepo
{
    public async Task<List<Person>> BuildReport(Filter filter)
    {
        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<Person>(true);
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.AltId) == false) { predicate = predicate.And(a => a.AltId == filter.AltId); }
        // Several more conditions
        // Insert filter for name/location of test with availability test date = test taken date
        using var context = _factory.CreateDbContext();
        {
            return await context.Person
                .Include(i => i.Employee)
                .Include(i => i.Student).ThenInclude(t => t.StudentTestAvailability)
                .Include(i => i.Student).ThenInclude(t => t.StudentTestTaken)
                .AsExpandable()
                .Where(predicate)
                .ToListAsync();
        }   
    }
}
```

The filter that is desired is to link the availability and taken tables by the date field retrieving
only records that match the nameId and / or locationId, depending on if provided (>0). The SQL previously
used was similar to this but more extensive.

```sql
SELECT p.*,s.*,sth.*,sta FROM People p
INNER JOIN Student S ON p.id = s.PersonId
LEFT JOIN StudentTestHistory sth ON s.id = sth.StudentId
LEFT JOIN StudentTestAvailability sta ON t.id = sta.StudentId
Where sth.StudentId = tta.StudentId 
    AND sth.DateTaken = sta.DateAvailable 
    AND sth.TestNameId = ata.TestNameId 
    AND sth.locationId = ata.locationId 
    AND (@nameId<1 OR sta.TestNameId=@nameId)
    AND (@locationId<1 OR sta.locationId=@locationId)
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

EDIT: In response to the question regarding navigation properties. Below are the navigation properties in question.

Comment: Show navigation properties which you have omitted. How `StudentTestHistory ` is related to `Student` entitty? Some navigation properties?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Updated question with the properties.

Comment: Can you move everything to original question classes? It is like a puzzle.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Moved them to the classes. Now that it is not a puzzle can you assist in how to solve this or is there more information you need?

Comment: Why do `StudentTestAvailability` and `StudentTestHistory` have FK properties *and* 1:n associations to the same entities?

Comment: @GertArnold The above is a scaled down version of the respective code. The reason for the FK's are due to a student can have multiple availability dates, times, locations and other criteria. The student can also have multiple tests of which can be taken during a certain availability or not, thus causing it to not have a required relationship to the availability. The other FK's are to the application table for the specific location and test that hold information directly related to them but not to the student. There are various other business rules and criteria that are in play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have rewritten your query to meet desired SQL. Removed `AsExpandable()`, it is not needed for `PredicateBuilder`, and actually I do not see why it is introduced here.

```cs
public class ReportRepo
{
    public async Task<List<Person>> BuildReport(Filter filter)
    {
        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<Person>(true);
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.AltId) == false) 
           { predicate = predicate.And(a => a.AltId == filter.AltId); }

        // Several more conditions
        // Insert filter for name/location of test with availability test date = test taken date

        using var context = _factory.CreateDbContext();
        {
            var persons = context.Person
                .Include(i => i.Employee)
                .Include(i => i.Student).ThenInclude(t => t.StudentTestAvailability)
                .Include(i => i.Student).ThenInclude(t => t.StudentTestTaken)
                .Where(predicate);

            var query = 
                from p in persons
                from sth in p.Student.StudentTestHistory
                from sta in p.Student.StudentTestAvailability
                where 
                    sth.StudentId == sta.StudentId 
                    && sth.DateTaken == sta.DateAvailable 
                    && sth.TestNameId == sta.TestNameId 
                    && sth.locationId == sta.locationId
                select new
                {
                    Person = p,
                    History = sth,
                    Avalability = sta
                };

            if (filter.NameId > 0)
                query = query.Where(x => x.Avalability.TestNameId == filter.NameId);
                    
            if (filter.LocationId > 0)
                query = query.Where(x => x.Avalability.LocationId == filter.LocationId);

            return await query
                .Select(x => x.Person)
                .ToListAsync();
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I included the `AsExpandable()` because I had seen it in the docs but did not fully understand it. Appreciate your pointing it out for removal. Also, I guess, I was attempting to build the entire query in the predicate using the predicatebuilder and did not think about doing this part after the initial query was built. I am used to working with Dapper and sending the SQL string. Thanks again for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: After trying to implement the code this morning, I noticed with the help of VS :) that the query 2nd and 3rd from are in error. They should be `from sth in p.Student.StudentTestHistory from sta in p.Student.StudentTestAvailability'. Do you agree with this modification?

Comment: Yes, it is my fault. Corrected.